# Ng-model в nested ng-repeat (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Дело касается **angular**.

В общем допустим у меня есть такой код:

```
<div ng-repeat="author in authors">
  <div ng-repeat="book in author.books">
    <ng-form name="book_form">   
      <input name="year" type="text" ng-model="??">
   </ng-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

`authors` лежит в scope контроллера и каждый "автор" имеет много-много книг.

- Как из контроллера получить значение инпута?
- Как заставить `ng-model` работать с многомерными списками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так — **ng-model="book.name"** — http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/TpDzM/

Comment: хм. первое что пришло мне в голову, но увы не заработало. 
ошибка оказалась в маленьком таком косяке :) криво воспользовался тернарным оператором в coffeescript

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Не работает примерчик.